# UnsupportedOperation: fileno

Tags: django, python-imaging-library

I get the following error message when trying to upload a file:

```
  File "/home/ymorin007/.virtualenvs/dvotedfan/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_resized/forms.py", line 47, in save
    thumb.save(new_content, format=img.format, quality=self.field.quality, **img.info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1439, in save
    save_handler(self, fp, filename)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py", line 471, in _save
    ImageFile._save(im, fp, [("jpeg", (0,0)+im.size, 0, rawmode)])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 476, in _save
    fh = fp.fileno()
UnsupportedOperation: fileno
```

I have install Pillow 3.1. and django-resized. Works perfectly locally but no on my external server.

Answer (score 0):

I've removed Pillow and now it works.

Comment: I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'` error on removing Pillow.